# Inserting created_at data with Laravel

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, laravel-4

I can't seem to insert `created_at` data in the database table with Laravel.
I'm trying to get that data from a POST and then trying to save it to the database.

I'm currently doing like this:

```
$create_dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s A", strtotime($_POST['post_date']." ".$_POST['post_time']));
$name = $_POST['name'];

$post = new Post();
$post->name = $name;
...
$post->created_at = $create_dt;
$post->save();
```

But it gives an error:

```
Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message in Carbon.php
```

and

```
Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing in Carbon.php
```

How can I solve this? Do I need to set `$timestamps` in my Models to false? (I really don't want do that because I'm fine with how it automatically inserts the `updated_at`)

Comment: Laravel will set the created_at field automaticly if you enable `$timestamps` in the model.

Comment: Do you really allow users to enter the date/time manually (never trust user input)

Comment: @Jerodev @MarkBaker I need to insert the `created_at` time manually because the user should be able to schedule a post in the future. I only gave the `User` model as an example.

Comment: In that case, why not add another field with a name that is not `created_at`

Comment: But then, there would be 2 creation dates. Isn't it? Sounds a little weird to me...

Comment: There wouldn't be two creation dates, there would be one actual creation date (automatically populated) and a `scheduled_at` or a `published_at` or whatever you choose to call it, each reflecting different things

Comment: Yeah. I figured. :) Already proceeding with that approach.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In your `User` model, add the following line in the `User` class:

```
public $timestamps = true;
```

Now, whenever you save or update a user, Laravel will automatically update the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

**Update:**
If you want to set the created at manually you should use the date format `Y-m-d H:i:s`. The problem is that the format you have used is not the same as Laravel uses for the `created_at` field.

**Update: Nov 2018 Laravel 5.6**
    `"message": "Access level to App\\Note::$timestamps must be public",`
    Make sure you have the proper access level as well. Laravel 5.6 is `public`.

Comment: I need to manually insert the `created_at` date, because the user should be able to schedule a post in the future. The `updated_at` should be insert automatically like Laravel does

Comment: I've used `Y-m-d H:i:s A`. Should I just drop the AM/PM part then?

Comment: I supose that could solve the problem. I have had similar issues in the past with the formatting of those dates.

Comment: On second thought, I'll use a separate field that you suggested in the comment. :) Quicker that way.

Comment: sure ? that its protected, in doc its public. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

Comment: Might have changed in Laravel 5.1, but the question was for Laravel 4. :)

Comment: This answer doesn't work in new versions. $timestamps should be 'public' and manually set of created_at doesn't work.

Comment: Is $timestamps should be public or protected as well..?

Comment: just change in: `public $timestamps = true;`

Comment: now you can used like this $post->created_at = now();

Comment: Isn't `$timestamps` optional as it's only necessary if it's set to `false`? I thought true is the default value from Laravel 4 to 6.

Comment: Sabrina Leggett's solution worked for me (Laravel 7)

Answer (score 35):

You can manually set this using Laravel, just remember to add 'created_at' to your $fillable array:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'created_at'];
```

Comment: There is no need to do that manually. Laravel already does it when we insert at first time.

Comment: for the most part - sometimes you may want to alter it slightly (maybe latency from an api?)

Comment: This is good answer. I need in my company to insert records where i need to change date. I try to found way but this with fillabe is realy simple and good.

Answer (score 29):

Currently (Laravel 5.4) the way to achieve this is:

```
$model = new Model();
$model->created_at = Carbon::now();
$model->save(['timestamps' => false]);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
$data = array();
$data['created_at'] =new \DateTime();
DB::table('practice')->insert($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

I like this approach:

```
$data = array();
$data['created_at'] = Carbon::now();

DB::table('list')->insert($data);
```

And this using the model:

```
List::insert([
'other' => 'something',
'created_at' => Carbon::now()
]);
```

**Note**: include `use Carbon\Carbon;`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to **unit test** that users weren't able to verify their email addresses after 1 hour had passed, so I didn't want to do any of the other answers since they would also persist when not unit testing, so I ended up just manually updating the row after insert:

```
// Create new user
$user = factory(User::class)->create();

// Add an email verification token to the 
// email_verification_tokens table
$token = $user->generateNewEmailVerificationToken();

// Get the time 61 minutes ago
$created_at = (new Carbon())->subMinutes(61);

// Do the update
\DB::update(
    'UPDATE email_verification_tokens SET created_at = ?',
    [$created_at]
);
```

Note: For anything other than unit testing, I would look at the other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `created_at` field **manually** using `Carbon` with any date format you want like this:

```
$model->created_at = Carbon::parse('your date in the format you prefer');
```

and don't forget to use Carbon like this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Model add

```
public $timestamps = true;
```

in your blade in the project we used  **Carbon** *search for it for more understanding or check this link [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/)*
like the below line

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($blog->created_at)->format('Y-m-d')}}
```