# created_at and updated_at don't update automatically on insert in laravel

Tags: laravel

I use laravel 8 :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('created_by_user')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Models:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Backend\MySQL;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user';
}
```

**In controller :**

```
use App\Models\User;

public function store(Request $request) {
    $data = [
        'name' => !empty($request->name) ? $request->name : 'Jony',
        'created_by'    => auth()->user()->id,
        'created_by_user'    => auth()->user()->name,
    ];
    User::insert($data);
}
```

I have successfully inserted. But the problem is that my created_by and updated_by columns are not updating automatically. Is there any way to solve this problem. In the `user` model I also don't set `protected $timestamps = false` but it doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26506825/14527588

Comment: insert function doesn't populate `created_at` & `updated_at`. user `create` or `save` functions instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

insert method is not for eloquent models and doesn't update created_at and updated_at.
you should use create method instead.

create method sets created_at and updated_at automatically

see this answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58075757/7689224

Answer (score 1):

You should use `create` instead of `insert`.

```
User::create($data);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use `create()` method instead of `insert()`

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $data = [
        'name' => !empty($request->name) ? $request->name : 'Jony',
        'created_by'    => auth()->user()->id,
        'created_by_user'    => auth()->user()->name,
    ];
    User::create($data);
}
```